# PHP ImagickException: not authorized

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick

Any ideas how to fix this ?

```
 ImagickException: not authorized `/tmp/magick-1552lvf2nIjaqx1W' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412
```

I thought it was a permission issue so just to test it out i set my /tmp dir to 777. No change. Its driving me crazy.

The command :

```
<?php


$image = new \Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' . $graph);
```

Comment: How about telling us what command caused this?

Comment: Pasting your command may give an insight - have you been able to get Imagick to work at all? Depending on your server the CHMOD could be 755

Comment: Have you tried setting and exporting the environment variable `MAGICK_TMPDIR` to someplace else where your script/CGI/program can write?

Comment: It might be your policy.xml having something in the ````<policymap>```` that [accidentally?] includes that file type as a matched pattern.

Comment: I tried 775 ,and changing the location: still having issues.

Comment: I commented out my policymap ><

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert:not authorized \`aaaa\` @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I have followed the below Steps to fix the Fatal error:

```
Uncaught ImagickException: not authorized `../../c02_001.pdf'
@ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412
```

---

1. `sudo vi policy.xml from etc/Imagemagick-6/`
2. comment the following line

   ```
   <!-- <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
   ```
3. Rewrite the following line

   ```
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
   ```

   to

   ```
   <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
   ```
4. `sudo apt-get install inkscape`
5. Restart apache with following command `sudo restart apache2`

Comment: <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />

 this worked for me.

Comment: If you're using php-fpm, use `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart` (or your version of PHP) instead of restarting apache.

Comment: thank you. I did use vim for this change. Not nano obviously! #realCoder

Comment: why step 4 `sudo apt-get install inkscape`? Everything works without it. Thanks, you saved my day too!

Comment: 5. sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 27):

Your policy "MVG" could be the reason. Just comment

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" />
```

in `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml` and restart Apache server.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I install stuff with brew. my etc with /ImageMagick/policy.xml was in usr/local/  - just if someone else end up here with my setup

Comment: you can run `locate policy.xm` to find the file in case the location differs. Then do the replace: `sudo sed -i -e 's/rights="none" pattern="PDF"/rights="read|write" pattern="PDF"/' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52677573/367456 below as well.

Comment: And what about NGINX ?

Comment: @kspr - for nginx you would restart php-fpm - with apache the php runtime is loaded as a module, for nginx (and other web servers) it's the seperate fastcgi version of php

Answer (score 1):

i hope this solution will help you
I'm facing the same issue and I'm on the live server i'm trying to follow above `Mikel Annjuk and hakre` answer so i cannot the change the file /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml so i contact to the server provider to edit file and send this url to follow step but there is answering me

" I am still working on this. The solution given in above link requires root access to the server  which is not possible in a shared server. But imagick is related to php. So let me try changing php version and see if that helps"

when i tired to resolve this on that time i have idea may be the issue of the file path where  I'm saving the file so I change to `base path to FCPATH` and the matter is solved.
i'm using Codeigniter base_url() to php FCPATH this is the point to solve this issue

but on svg converter show "no decode delegate" issue

add the following lines in the start of file or code

like this

```
$usmap = file_get_contents(base_url('convert/plus.svg')); 
     $find_string   = '<svg';
$position = strpos($usmap, $find_string);

   $svg_file_new ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.substr($usmap, $position).'</svg>';
       file_put_contents(FCPATH.'convert/plus.svg', $svg_file_new);

        $usmap = base_url('convert/plus.svg'); 
$im = new Imagick($usmap);  
$im->setImageFormat("jpg"); 

$im->writeImage(FCPATH .'convert/plus.jpg');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

above code first, get the SVG code from the file and add XML version code then put it into the file and then convert SVG to any type of image like jpg

sorry for my English

Comment: I am not sure XML/SVG files should be read as blobs. Try reading as a normal image.

Comment: just simple code $pdfPath = base_url('convert/ResumeAnusShahbaz0.jpeg'); 
$im = new imagick($pdfPath); 
$im->setImageFormat('pdf');  
$im->writeImage(FCPATH .'convert/ResumeAnusShahbaz0.pdf');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();

Comment: it work on many image format still i'm find one issue svg to other  above 12 i have checked its work  and another format i'm trying to convert lest how many format work on this code

Comment: i have the solution for svg converter update my answer

Answer (score 0):

An "strace" of the PHP process shown the following:

> sh: inkscape: command not found

I fixed this by:

```
apt-get install inkscape
```