# Laravel PDF-to-image: ImagickException: not authorized

Tags: laravel

if i upload a image in my tool and click on next step then following error occurs:

```
ImagickException: not authorized `/tmp/comcard_NEgyzR.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412
/vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php in line 169
```

Any idea. This happend from one moment to another.

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to help you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert:not authorized \`aaaa\` @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue after PHP update, not upgrade. Was able to solve it with help from **spatie** git-hub page with below instruction.

---

It seems this error started happening for a lot of people last week. No real reason why though. To partially fix...

**Step 1:**
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

**Step2:**
Add/edit the following lines

`<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="LABEL" />`

You may also need to comment out the MGV line if you have it. I did not.

**Step3:**
Restart web server AND php-fpm. i.e. (on nginx/php7.2)
sudo service nginx restart
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm

Follow the below link for more details if the above 3 steps does not work for you.
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1268#issuecomment-429928562

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue solution change file path correctly  change base path to FCPATH of the file where is the saving

[PHP ImagickException: not authorized][1]

Complete Solution link  [1]: [PHP ImagickException: not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599727/php-imagickexception-not-authorized/56402614#56402614)