# Ubuntu 14.04, php 5.5.9 ImageMagick crashes during pdf to jpg conversion

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I try to convert pdf to jpg. This is the simple code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pdf8='https://my.novaposhta.ua/orders/printMarking100x100/orders[]/20450189416569/type/pdf8/apiKey/8c813355bb8499c718bea833483bba50';
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($pdf8);//<!-- ImageMagick crashes here
$imagick->writeImage('./output.jpg');
```

ImageMagick crashes without any errors! So I cant event understand whats wrong. php.ini has memory_limit set to 2048M.
I tried to reinstall ImageMagick but nothing changed.

I did this:

```
sudo apt-get purge imagemagick
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install imagemagick -y
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick -y
sudo php5enmod imagick
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Please help! I have spant the whole day for this with no result. What do I do wrong? Or how can I convert pdf to jpg in other way?

Any help appriciated!

Comment: Have you tried to run ImageMagick outside PHP with the `-debug` flag?

Comment: Not sure about those square brackets `[]` in the filename... can you try without?

Comment: I would very much recommend you to upgrade your system. You're running unsupported versions of both the OS and PHP. Neither of them gets security updates anymore.

Comment: I have tried to do that without [] - no result

Comment: How can I run ImageMagick outside PHP with the -debug flag?

Comment: I have just tried it and get an error (not authorized), followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/52677573/1213708 and it worked.

Comment: You need to have Ghostscript installed. And also modify your Imagemagick policy.xml file so that it permits the use of PDF/EPS etc files. It was restricted due to a bug in Ghostscript a while back.